# Getting an error when time is included in a date field. Oracle Apex From

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a form that updates a table and the column that I'm having issues with is START_DT which is a DATE column in the DB.

And my form has that field `P7_START_DT` is a Text Field and I have also tried it as  a Date field as well, with the same error.

I have a update process the updates that START_DT column, if I use a date in this format (11/08/2023) it updates just fine, but I want to include the time as well like this (11/08/2023 11:10:10 PM) and if I use this format I get the following error.

```
: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Here is the PL/SQL Code.

```
START_DT = :P7_START_DT
```

And the date in the form for `P7_START_DT = 11/09/2023 12:08:06 AM`
I've tried to format the data like this and I get the same error.

```
START_DT = to_date(:P7_START_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following attribute:
Application Definition > Globalization > "Application Date Format". By default this will be a date format with no time portion. Change it to an format that has a time portion, eg DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI.
This is the format that the application is expecting for date fields and that will be used to display dates. Note that all page items are just strings under the hood, and apex is doing the conversion to date (or any other non-character datatype) under the hood. A `TO_DATE` will never work on a page item (unless you are using it in a pl/sql block to do a custom process of course).

After making this change you should be able to enter dates in that format in your page item.